# SKProduct multiple files

Tags: ios, cocoa

The API for SKProduct suggests that it is possible to have more than one downloadable file associated with a single in-app purchase. However in iTunes Connect I do not see any way to achieve this. Is it possible to do this, in particular when hosting with Apple? If so then how?

Answer (score 0):

Use in-app purchase XCode target to create the package file. Then you can enable Apple hosted content from iTunes Connect

Comment: As far as I can tell, this still only allows one download per IAP.